# How to filter a Django queryset via text field in the latest corresponding entry in a separate model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model where I needed historical data for a couple specific fields, so I put those fields into a separate model with a foreign key relationship.

Something sort of like this:

```
class DataThing(models.Model):
    # a bunch of fields here...


class DataThingHistory(models.Model):
    datathing_id = models.ForeignKey('DataThing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text_with_history = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    # other similar fields...
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I'm trying to filter the former model using a text field in the latest corresponding entry in the latter.

Basically if these were not separate models I'd just try this:

```
search_results = DataThing.objects.filter(text_with_history__icontains=searchterm)
```

But I haven't figured out a good way to do this across this one-to-many relationship and using only the entry with the latest timestamp in the latter model, at least by using the Django ORM.

I have an idea of how to do the query I want using raw SQL, but I'd really like to avoid using raw if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution makes use of [`distinct(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) which is currently only supported by Postgres:

```
latest_things = DataThingHistory.objects.
    order_by('datathing_id_id', '-timestamp').
    distinct('datathing_id_id')

lt_with_searchterm = DataThingHistory.objects.
    filter(id__in=latest_things, text_with_history__icontains=searchterm)

search_results = DataThing.objects.filter(datathinghistory__in=lt_with_searchterm)
```

This should result in single db query. I have split the query for readability, but you can nest it into a single statement. Btw, as you might see here, `foo_id` is not a good name for a `ForeignKey` field.

Comment: Thanks for this, I just tried this and it does result in one query. I'll have to do some testing and see how well it runs in practice, but this seems to solve my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

You would do the same by querying `DataThing` while referring to `DataThingHistory`:

```
search_results = DataThing.objects.filter(datathinghistory__text_with_history__icontains=searchterm)
```

Check django doc on [how to query on reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

**Edit:**

My previous answer is incomplete. In order to search on latest history for each `DataThing`, you need to `annotate` on timestamp using `Max`:

```
from django.db.models import Max

search_results = search_results.values('field1', 'field2',...).annotate(latest_history=Max('datathinghistory__timestemp'))
```

This wouldn't give you complete `DataThing` objects, but you could add as many fields to `values` as you want.

Comment: How would I only check the `DataThingHistory` object with the latest `timestamp`? It seems that just doing the query you describe searches all the related `DataThingHistory` entries.

Comment: Sorry I totally missed your requirement. I edited my answer, see if that makes sense.